# Fake token for Phantom app on mobile (devnet)

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, phantom, solana-pay, dapp

Hi I am developing a mobile dapp. Everything seems to be on the right track however I need fake tokens on my Phantom app (devnet) to test my app. My application is not complete yet, I think need more functionality so I think I can't use real tokens. So is there any way for me to get fake tokens on Phantom mobile app? Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Metaboss is the easiest way to create an SPL token with associated metadata on Solana right now: https://metaboss.rs/create.html#create

Once you create this, simply transfer it to your Phantom wallet

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new token on Solana devnet. As you are creating the token on devnet, it can be used for development purposes.

Note:- We can create the new token on mainnet by pointing the network to mainnet-beta. Untill the token is listed on a trading platform, it's value is 0.

```
// snippet taken from https://spl.solana.com/token
import { createMint } from '@solana/spl-token';
import { clusterApiUrl, Connection, Keypair, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL } from '@solana/web3.js';

const payer = Keypair.generate();
const mintAuthority = Keypair.generate();
const freezeAuthority = Keypair.generate();

const connection = new Connection(
  clusterApiUrl('devnet'),
  'confirmed'
);

const mint = await createMint(
  connection,
  payer,
  mintAuthority.publicKey,
  freezeAuthority.publicKey,
  9 // We are using 9 to match the CLI decimal default exactly
);

console.log(mint.toBase58());
```

Comment: Sorry I tried but failed, @solana/spl-token doesn't seem to work on react-native. It throws the error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: BigInt. Can you give more clear instructions?

Comment: BigInt is not available on React Native. You can add a shim for that using big-integer package. Here are the details:- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28492